# mkdir: can't create directory '/consul/extra-config: Permission denied Pod on Openshift 4.6

Tags: openshift, consul, hashicorp-vault, helm3

After the installation of the Hashicorp Vault with consul, Iam getting the error permission denied.

Tried with

1. oc adm policy add-scc-to-user -z service account -n namespace privileged
2. Oc command with anyuid

Still the error not resolved

Iam following the helm chart to install the Hashicorp Vault with consul: https://github.com/openlab-red/hashicorp-vault-for-openshift

Kindly help on this

Answer (score -1):

Issue got resolved I just set the runasuser as 0 and privileged is set to true then I executed this below command:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user -z service account -n namespace privileged
```

Note: This was done in Dev. So, if you prefer other ways please answer to this thread.

Comment: It will be great if you mention the detailed steps.